# kinect depth value

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that each pixel in the depth image is supposed to relate to the distance

of that part of the scene, but no unit ( not [mm] ).

How do we translate from these value to a distance measurement in some kind of

useful units like [mm]?

Can you tell me the changable fomula?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39662/kinect-depth-value/) by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [openni_camera wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera#openni_camera.2BAC8-electric.ROS_API) describes how to interpret the data from each topic published by the camera. Specifically:

```
depth/image_raw (sensor_msgs/Image)
    Raw image from device. Contains uint16 depths in mm.
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1